# MySQL PHP: How can I combine this nested WHILE loop into a single query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code that works, but I know it's not very efficient and I could probably consolidate this into a single SQL query.  Should I bother?  And if so, how?

```
function get_rnds_by_judge($judge_id) {
global $connection;
$sql = "SELECT *
        FROM Round_User
        LEFT JOIN Round
        ON Round_User.RndID = Round.RndID
        WHERE Round_User.UserID = '$judge_id'
        ";
$rnd_set = mysql_query($sql, $connection);
confirm_query($rnd_set);
return $rnd_set;
}

function get_users_by_round_and_role($round_id, $role_id) {
    global $connection;
    $sql = "SELECT *
            FROM User
            LEFT JOIN Round_User
            ON User.UserID = Round_User.UserID
            WHERE Round_User.RndID = '$round_id' and User.UserRoleID = '$role_id'
            ";
    $rnd_set = mysql_query($sql, $connection);
    confirm_query($rnd_set);
    return $rnd_set;
}

$rnd_set = get_rnds_by_judge($_SESSION[UserID]);
while($rnd_row = mysql_fetch_array($rnd_set)){
    echo "<li data-role=\"list-divider\">";
    echo $rnd_row[RndTitle];
    echo "</li>";
    $rs_set = get_users_by_round_and_role($rnd_row[RndID], 7);
    while($rs_row = mysql_fetch_array($rs_set)){
        echo "<li>";
        echo "<a href=\"#\">{$rs_row[UserFirstName]}</a>";
        echo "</li>";
    }
}
```

The part I trip up on is how do I take the `RndID` and `UserID` from my joining `Round_User` table and go get data from 2 different tables then bring it all back together.

Comment: Can you show us the table designs?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without seeing table structures and sample data, but you are probably looking for something like this

```sql
SELECT u.*
  FROM User u LEFT JOIN 
       Round_User ru ON u.UserID = ru.UserID
 WHERE ru.RndID IN (
       SELECT ru2.RndId
         FROM Round_User ru2 LEFT JOIN 
              Round r ON ru2.RndID = r.RndID
        WHERE ru2.UserID = '$judge_id') 
   AND u.UserRoleID = 7
```

*The query obviously has not been tested.*

Comment: @Chaz Did it help? Do you need more help with your question?